# sh.status() error processing query: ns=config.mongosTree

Tags: mongodb

if I run sh.status in mongos I get the error:

```
assert: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "error processing query: ns=config.mongosTree: ping $gt new Date(1532712420740)\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n No query solutions",
        "code" : 2
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:290:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1312:5
printShardingStatus@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:611:13
sh.status@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:78:5
@(shell):1:1

2018-07-27T11:28:05.644-0600 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "error processing query: ns=config.mongosTree: ping $gt new Date(1532712420740)\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n No query solutions",
        "code" : 2
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:290:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1312:5
printShardingStatus@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:611:13
sh.status@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:78:5
```

I reinstalled all mongo-enterprise packages but still the error persist, all the shards are working correctly, since I can perform find from mongos.

thanks